# What is this Algorithm called? [Traveling Salesman Problem]

Tags: algorithms, problem-solving

I've been thinking about the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem). In examining it and grids of cities, I noticed that I could frequently pick out the shortest route just by staring at it. Granted, I couldn't necessarily get the solutions for the complex grids, but if I could get the simple ones there had to be a way to consistently solve them.

I realized that most(all the ones I've seen) take a circular route around the cities, follow a bit of an outer border. My idea was to start with an algorithm that marks the outermost points of a grid on as many sides as possible. Which is always at least 4(unless you have less than 4) one city for each cardinal direction. Something like this:

(Given, I'm only human so I mostly guessed which cities would be chosen. It's possible the initial algorithm would have chosen differently or chosen more than 4. For the purpose of examples though...)

[image: Map 1]

Then the algorithm finds another set of the outermost points, not including points previously found. It matches these points with the closest red line, and inserts itself there.

[image]

it repeats this until all points have been selected and joined.

[image]
[image]

This seems to work pretty well for smaller simpler selections of cities. Whether or not it falls apart for larger more complex models is as of yet unknown. I suspect a city could be made that breaks this.

Anyways, I'm mostly curious what this sort of algorithm would be called. I find it fascinating, and I'd like to learn more about it.

Is this an actually solution to the problem, or just a close approximation?

Comment: It sounds like a variant of convex hull.

Comment: By " I noticed that I could frequently pick out the shortest route just by staring at it" you actually mean "I set the most powerful parallel processor known to humankind on the problem"

Comment: @RichardTingle Yup pretty much. :P

Comment: @Ucenna You may be onto something. Suppose you have computed the convex hull, and now you want to add some of the "concave" points. Compute the center of gravity (or some time of center) of the hull, and sort the remaining points by their distance from the center. This may speed up the discovery of the closest of the concave points (farthest ones first).

Comment: @FrankHileman Certainly, it could be optimized further by using the central point of the grid to minimize necessary permutations.

Comment: It is probably an heuristic approximation. TSP is known to be intractable

Comment: If extended to quasi-planar points in 3d it'd make for a neat "edge ring from point cloud" function. Of course, in either number of dimensions there's plenty of datasets that would be pathological and create a mess, but hey, in actual use of some kinds you have a person eyeballing some data and deciding that some algorithm would be a good fit fbr the shape of it or a subset.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're doing is making a convex hull. Your algorithm won't be a perfect solution, just an approximation. Consider the following grid:

[image]

Your algorithm would start by doing something like this:

[image]

Then things get more tricky, your algorithm would make one of the following choices depending on how it's coded:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Only one of these is correct. In theory your algorithm could work, but it would need more polish before then. You'd need some logic to help decide how the inner cities connect with the outer cities. There's a few methods, you could use the greedy algorithm, but that's inaccurate in most situations as it would be in this one. Alternatively, the brute force method is applicable. There's much less permutations to consider this time, as you aren't connecting every combination of cities. Keep in mind that you'd need to consider the distance of OuterCity->InnerCity->OuterCity and not just the distance between OuterCity->InnerCity.